# Кто такие архаровцы?

Tags: этимология, фразеология

Часто слышу выражение "архаровец". Если я ничего не путаю, это означает хулигана. А откуда вообще такое выражение пошло?

Answer (score 8):

Из "Энциклопедического словаря крылатых слов и выражений" (2008).

> Из истории России. Во времена императрицы Екатерины II обер-полицмейстером Москвы, то есть главой всей полиции города, был Николай Петрович Архаров (1742—1797), который разработал систему жестких мер по подавлению преступности в Москве, он же суровыми, решительными мерами подавил Чумной бунт (1771) в Москве. Это не понравилось многим москвичам, и Н.П. Архаров снискал среди них дурную славу, которая распространилась и на всех его подчиненных — московских полицейских: их в народе стали неодобрительно называть «архаровцами». 
>   С течением времени история слова забылась, но осталось его негативное значение, и «архаровцами» стали называть уже не блюстителей порядка, а всех его нарушителей — грабителей, шумных бродяг, хулиганов и вообще отчаянных людей, готовых на всякого рода преступления.

Answer (score 1):

```
АРХА́РОВЕЦ, архаровца, муж. (разг., бран.). Хулиган, озорник, отчаянный. (первонач. сыщик, агент Архарова, московского обер-полицмейстера, а потом губернатора в конце 18 в.)
```

Толковый словарь Ушакова. Д.Н. Ушаков. 1935-1940.

Забавно, что слово "хулиган" тоже произошло от имени собственного:

"Происходит от англ. hooligan «буян, нарушитель порядка, хулиган», от неустановленной формы. Существуют три версии происхождения названия: от имени ирландца Патрика Хулихэна (Patrick Houlihan), дебоширившего в Лондонском районе Southwark; от слова hooley (на ирландском — «шумная алкогольная вечеринка»); от названия уличной банды Hooley gang в северном районе Лондона Ислингтон (Islington). Англ. слово встречается с 1890-х, в начале XX века оно стало интернациональным."

Ср. архаровец и тимуровец.